# Compare dates from one timezone with dates from another timezone

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, wordpress

I have a MySQL database that is running in `America/New_York` and a node server that is running on UTC. I need to run a query against the MySQL database from node and compare times. The time comparison is pretty close, so I need to do a timezone conversion.

**Note**: This is a Wordpress database controlled by a third party; I cannot `ALTER` the database in any way.

Currently, I am just doing this:

```
comparisonDate = new Date((new Date).setHours(new Date().getHours() - 4)));
```

Specifically subtracting 4 hours from the node server's UTC date to compare to MySQL.

This works fine, but I'm concerned about what will happen after daylight savings time. I would rather do the conversion (I can guarantee that I know the MySQL server timezone ahead of time).

[`moment-timezone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone) seems promising, but when I do

```
moment.tz('America/New_York').toDate()
```

I get still get the date with UTC time and not EST/EDT time.

How can I do the appropriate timezone conversion consistently in JavaScript?

Comment: General rule: perform date/time comparisons by normalizing values to UTC. To do this you will need to always store the UTC offset with the datetime value, unfortunately MySQL does not have a "Local+Offset" datetype comparable to MSSQL Server's `datetimeoffset` type, so you'll need a separate `int` column to store the offset (in minutes or seconds). As for daylight savings, use a library that maintains its own database (with historical daylight-savings dates too), I believe the Moment library does this.

Comment: @Dai important to say I have absolutely no control over the MySQL database -- it is a wordpress database hosted and controlled by a client

Comment: How is date and timezone information stored in the database?

Comment: @Dai there is a `post_date` column that is a datetime column. That is what I am comparing to. This would be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` and should be based on America/New_York time

Comment: I see WordPress also has a `post_date_gmt` column. Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: @Dai great find, this is probably particularly what I need. So I can depend on GMT/UTC being similar enough for this comparison?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, GMT **is** UTC. WordPress likely gets the `post_date_gmt` value from the same UTC functions, they just decided to name it GMT.

Comment: UTC is the new name for the time standard formerly known as GMT. The old name is still used in the British Isles for their non-Summer time zone, but it is no longer the name for global standard time.  Nonetheless, they are equivalent as time zone designators.

Comment: @MarkReed sure, just checking. As I understand any differences between GMT and UTC are on the order of seconds rather than anything that would matter in most cases

Comment: There is no difference.  They are the same.  Down to tiny fractions of a second.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue of timezone conversion.

I did like this and it is working fine.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var timezone = require('moment-timezone');

var now = timezone(moment()).tz("America/New_York");
```

Here `now` variable gives time of `America/New_York`.

After daylight savings time moment-timezone takes care of that.

In moment-timezone they have `Parsing Ambiguities` section which explains this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for you.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```

using this php function you can set default timezone.